# $base_url problems in forms after upgrading Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I believe I followed the instructions when upgrading Drupal (7.33 -> 7.39), but managed to break it.

The setup: The Drupal site is behind a reverse proxy:

```
<Location /app>
  ProxyPass http://back.example.com/drupal
  ProxyPassReverse http://back.example.com/drupal
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /drupal /app
</Location>
```

And in the `sites/default/settings.php`, there's this bit:

```
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';
if (!empty($_SERVER[$conf['reverse_proxy_header']])) {
  $base_url = 'http://front.example.com/app';
}
```

The problem: While some forms seem to work, generating a correct `action` attribute (`<form action="/app/..." ...>`), most (notably, everything in Admin area) are ignoring the `$base_url`, generating `<form action="/drupal/..." ...>`, so submit obviously fails.

I took a look at the source, but I can't figure out how it worked in the first place, because, as far as I can see, `action` is generated from `drupal_build_form`, which reads the action data from `element_info('form')`, which is populated by `system_element_info`, which, in turn, calls `request_uri()` - and there is nothing in `request_uri()` about `$base_url`.

I tried to clear caches with `drush` just in case I was missing something in the database, and it did not help.

EDIT: It seems most of the links are calling the `url($path)` function, which does the right thing. But it is not being called for the form's `action` attribute, except for a form that is being rendered from a plugin (and which doesn't seem to use `element_info`, but calls `url` to construct its `action`).

EDIT2: If it was not clear, `$base_url` has the correct value; it is just not getting applied (and I can't see where it would be applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed in `system_element_info` calling `request_uri` which is not taking care of $base_url...

But as always in drupal you can alter things:

```
function yourmodule_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  global $base_url;

  // Use $base_url for form action
  $type['form']['#action'] = $base_url . request_path();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did patch the issue, so at least the site is usable. It still behaves weirdly - e.g. the forms have `target="_new"` - but that's much less important. However, the big question I have is - how the heck did it work in the first place, before the update?!? (I backed up the old code, and it is equivalent. I put it up back on Apache and it doesn't work either any more.) Anyway, I will accept this answer tentatively, unless someone can explain the cause of this.